# how to display image with Uploadify 2.1.4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using Uploadify/asp.net mvc 3 to upload images. Is it possible to display the image before uploading it? if yes how?

my uploadcontrol:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/swfobject.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js")"></script>
<input type="file" name="fileInput1" id="fileInput1" />
<span id="result"></span><a href="javascript:$('#fileInput1').uploadifyUpload();">Upload
    File</a> <span id="showimage"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#fileInput1").uploadify({
            uploader: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploadify.swf")',
            script: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',
            fileDataName: 'file',
            buttonText: 'File Input 1...',
            multi: false,
            sizeLimit: 1000000,
            simUploadLimit: 1,
            cancelImg: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cancel.png")',
            auto: false,
            onError: function (a, b, c, d) {
                if (d.status == 404)
                    alert("Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: " + "<?= getcwd() ?>");
                else if (d.type === "HTTP") {
                    console.log("error " + d.type + ": " + d.status);
                    alert("error " + d.type + ": " + d.status);
                }
                else if (d.type === "File Size")
                    $("#result").html("file too big");
                //alert(c.name + " " + d.type + " Limit: " + Math.round(d.info / (1024 * 1024)) + "MB");
                else
                    alert("error " + d.type + ": " + d.text);
            },
            onComplete: function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                $("#showimage").html("<img src=" + fileObj.filePath + "height='500' width='500'/><br />");
            }
        });


    });

</script>
```

controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
                var filename = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(filename);
            }



           // return Json(file);
           //return name;
           return Json(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @rouen's answer about client side limitations, you could use the [HTML 5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) to achieve this. This obviously restricts it only to modern browsers but it could be a compromise. It's progressive enhancement: clients using modern browsers get immediate preview and feedback whereas clients using legacy browsers will have to upload the file first and see the preview afterwards (in addition to the message about upgrading their browsers of course which should be shown to all of them).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cant do this (access local filesystem by javascript in fact), for security reasons.

You can however use this workaround :
Right after choosing file, do "background" upload, store this file as temporary, and on client side show thumnail from it.. of course, this would seems like preview only if it is fast enough, and there is potentially increased traffic due to this roundtrips.

Answer (score 0):

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var appData = Server.MapPath("~/app_data");
                var filename = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(filename);
            }


           return Content(filename);
        }

            onComplete: function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                $("#showimage").html("<img src=" + response + "height='500' width='500'/><br />");
            }
```